# pandoc gives long author lists and inconsistent citations

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, pandoc, citations

I have a small Rmd document that I am compiling to a word file in Rstudio:

````
---
output: 
  word_document
---
```{r, results='hide', echo=FALSE}
library("knitcitations")
cleanbib()
```
This is an inline citation [`r citet("10.1038/nature08835")`]. 

The same citation again [`r citet("10.1038/nature08835")`].

BIBLIOGRAPHY
------------
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
bibliography()
```
````

The problem is that the first citation awkwardly has the whole author list inline, while subsequent references and the bibliography have shorter, easier to read lists.

> This is an inline citation [Rasmussen, Li, Lindgreen, Pedersen,
>   Albrechtsen, Moltke, Metspalu, Metspalu, Kivisild, Gupta, Bertalan,
>   Nielsen, Gilbert, Wang, Raghavan, Campos, Kamp, Wilson, Gledhill,
>   Tridico, Bunce, Lorenzen, Binladen, Guo, Zhao, Zhang, Zhang, Li, Chen,
>   Orlando, Kristiansen, Bak, Tommerup, Bendixen, Pierre, Gr, Meldgaard,
>   Andreasen, Fedorova, Osipova, Higham, Ramsey, Hansen, Nielsen,
>   Crawford, S, Sicheritz-Pontén, Villems, Nielsen, Krogh, Wang, and
>   Willerslev (2010)].
>
> The same citation again [Rasmussen, Li, Lindgreen,
>   et al. (2010)].
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> [1] M. Rasmussen, Y. Li, S. Lindgreen, et
>   al. "Ancient human genome sequence of an extinct Palaeo-Eskimo". In:
>   Nature 463.7282 (Feb. 2010), pp. 757-762. DOI: 10.1038/nature08835. .

Why is it happening, and how do I get it to use a reasonable, consistent format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `longnamesfirst` option in `BibOptions`, a function inside the `RefManageR` package. Add this to your "preamble".

````
```{r, results='hide', echo=FALSE}
  library(knitcitations)
  library(RefManageR)
  BibOptions(longnamesfirst=FALSE)
  cleanbib()
```
````

and it works as you expected. You can find more options by looking in `?BibOptions`.